# HttpURLConnection Only raw data in localhost

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

The java code insert raw data into test.php, but it only works with localhost url, and don't with public ip

My urls,

```
//this URL work perfect, output: {"a":"b"} phpOK
postJSON("http://192.168.1.100/test.php?username=user&password=pass");

//this URL don't work, output: phpOK
postJSON("http://myddns.net/test.php?username=user&password=pass");
```

Code to send data,

```
public String postJSON(String URL, String jsonStr) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    StringBuffer response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(jsonStr.getBytes().length);

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

JSONObject jsonStr= new JSONObject();
jsonStr.put("a", "b");

        DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        printout.writeBytes(jsonStr);
        printout.flush();
        printout.close();

        //if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        br.close();
    } finally {
        if(urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        if(response != null)
            return response.toString();
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

My PHP,

```
//in test.php
<?php
 $phpInput = file_get_contents('php://input');
 echo $phpInput." phpOK";
if(isset($_GET['username']) & isset($_GET['password']))
 echo "extra vars catched"
?>
```

I test in a real phone using 3G data and... My server is blocking in some way the public ip, because when I use the local ip it's work perfect. Blocking the writing output stream: urlConnection.getOutputStream()

Comment: `//this URL don't work, output: phpOK`. ? If the output is phpOK then i would say that it works.

Comment: because, the raw data don't show anything.
output is:

echo file_get_contents('php://input') + "phpOK";

Comment: You are unclear an looking for help in the wrong way.

Comment: I'm using HTTPConnection in Android to post data into php server. The problem is that only work with local url 192.168.1.100, and don't with my global ip, like http://global_ip:1994/test.php
Note: the client and the server are connect in the same router

Comment: `the client and the server are connect in the same router`??? Your server was on the internet you said. Your note does not make sense.

Comment: You still have not edited your post with code, response and exeptions, stacktraces. So you still ask for help in the wrong way.

Comment: I don't say that, I say that client and server are running and the same computer and connected in the same router becase the client (android emulator) and server (wampserver) is inside in the same computer. I don't can write data in the php://input using the external url. I got test the external url in a real phone with data 4G provider and answer her.

Comment: Whole story still does not make sense as there are two servers in your story. Which is uncommon. You have an Android client runing in an emulator on a computer. Then on the same computer you have an xamp server. And then you have an external url of another server. Ok that is your setup. Now tell what you want and what the problem is. Your client will try to connect whith which server?

Comment: `I say that client and server are running and the same computer and connected in the same router`. Impossible. Only your computer will be connected to your router. Not the emulator. You do not even need a router for an emulator and xwamp setup as you have.

Comment: So you are trying to connect to the same wamp server. Once using internal ip of your computer and once using external ip of your router. !!! If you only had said that at the beginninglll And only emulator? No real Android device?

Comment: Please quote in such a way that it looks like a quote. This is confusing now.

Comment: "And then you have an external url of another server" @greenapps The external url point to my computer, egg: myip.ddns.net -> 200.200.200.200:1994 -> my router forwards to my local ip 192.168.1.100:80 (external 1994 to internal 80), because I forward the port 1994 to my local ip reserved, and my server request the info.

Comment: "Now tell what you want and what the problem is. Your client will try to connect whith which server?" @greenapps The problem is that when I use the local ip in my java code, then can post data in the php and I can get the data in the php file using the function file_get_contents('php://input'), but then I use my external ip, then don't can write data.That is my the server reply with: "phpOK" but don't "{"a", "b"} phpOK". {"a", "b"} represent the raw data writed in the php file. I think that my wampserver denied write data for public ip.

Comment: "Only your computer will be connected to your router. Not the emulator." @greenapps I meant to say, that I running the emulator in my computer that runing my server. Apology

Comment: Apache acess log
with url "http://myddns.net/test.php":
180.64.234.249 - - [15/Nov/2016:05:57:27 -0500] "GET test.php HTTP/1.1" 200
php://input: phpOK

with url "http://192.168.1.100/test.php":
192.168.1.100 - - [15/Nov/2016:06:02:40 -0500] "GET test.php HTTP/1.1" 200
php://input: {"a":"b"} phpOK

I need this "{"a":"b"} phpOK" and don't this "phpOK"

Comment: Do you think we can read all that stuff in a comment?

Comment: `"GET test.php HTTP/1.1"` ??? A GET request???

Comment: `Code to send data,` It is already long time to post the complete send code.

Comment: `Code to send data,`. Post complete code. Also the code to read the response (the echos from php).

Comment: I test in a real phone using 3G data and... the same thing... My server is blocking in some way public ip. Blocking the writing output stream: urlConnection.getOutputStream()

Comment: I update the ask @greenapps

Comment: I use urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); this work in local ip.

Comment: `My server is blocking in some way the public ip, because when I use the local ip it's work perfect. `. If there was no connection you would not receive back " phpOk".. `return response.toString();` is that " phpOK"?

Comment: And explain where you do a POST request  Apache talks about GET.

Comment: `Blocking the writing output stream: urlConnection.getOutputStream() `. Your sever can not block that. But you pass the first question: Does the client connect to begin with?

Comment: Is there a proxy in between? Some proxies convert POST requests to GET requests. It is strange that your Apache logs only talk about GET.

Comment: `My server is blocking in some way public ip`. You should not only bind your xamp server to local host but to all ips. But you will have a connect exception then. And you did not talk about exeptions. Please look in the logcat.

Comment: "If there was no connection you would not receive back " phpOk".. " @greenapps Correction: My server is blocking in some way the public ip for writen data in php file. Is like that I need allow a php permission for public ip write data.

Comment: "And explain where you do a POST request Apache talks about GET" @greenapps Maybe, because I'm use vars in the URL: "test.php?username=user&password=pass" see the edited ask

Comment: "Your sever can not block that. But you pass the first question: Does the client connect to begin with?" @greenapps Yes, but the function that write the JSON don't (in public ip, in local ip is fine). Maybe a firewall bloqued?

Comment: "Is there a proxy in between? Some proxies convert POST requests to GET requests. It is strange that your Apache logs only talk about GET." @greenapps I'm using a free ddns by no-ip.com

Comment: '"And you did not talk about exeptions. Please look in the logcat" @greenapps as I said, no execeptions, because I don't not how to catch the exception in this line, like -exception if the writeoutputstrem don't can write data- in this line "DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());"

Comment: No error log in Apache, PHP or MySQL.

Comment: My ddns just direct to my_global_ip:1994/test.php?username=user&password=pass In my router config, the port 1994 is seted to forward to my computer that host the server. Maybe the port 1994 is not the best for write json data.

Comment: I test also the App (client) in my phone using 3G, and don't work the output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

The problem is my record type of DDNS.

I config my ddns with record type URL, protocol HTTP:// and IP X.X.X.X:1994

I change to record type DNS Host (A), IPv4 Address: myip only X.X.X.X , without port.

In my URL client, I set the port in the URL.

I change the record type of my DDNS and,
http://myddns.net/test.php?username=user&password=pass
to this:
http://myddns.net:1994/test.php?username=user&password=pass

Comment: Good you found it!

Comment: Thank you for helping @greenapps